# How can i integrate Google Assistant to a phonegap app?

Tags: phonegap-plugins, actions-on-google, phonegap, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

The use case is to integrate Google assistant feature in phone-app(Android and iOS) app.
We have integrated Google Assistant with Dialogflow now we want to integrate Google Assitant with a phonegap mobile app.

Please help to understand how this can be done.

Comment: "Integrate" means a lot of things. To understand what you want to do, it would be very helpful to see example conversations, use cases, and code that you're currently with or problems that you're encountering.